# what is updated in honeycomb 3.2.1?

Tags: updates, motorola-xoom, 3.2-honeycomb

My wifi Xoom was just updated to 3.2.1.  Anyone know what this update contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Motorola's Xoom Support forums has a thread that is updated when updates go out, and contains links to the lists of changes in the updates [which (for US Wifi Xooms) is here](https://supportforums.motorola.com/message/475264#475264).

According to that two software updates have gone out in the last few weeks, HTK55D and HTK75D the first contains security updates, the second updates to included apps. Specifically they contain:

**HTK55D**

> Platform security fixes :
>
> - DigiNotar certificate revocation
>   The
>   security fix removes a compromised root Certificate Authority (CA).
> - libpng security update
>    Libpng has been updated to version 1.2.46 to
>   correct for multiple publicly-known security issues.

**HTK75D**

> - Android™ Market has been updated.
> - Android™ Books has been updated.

Answer (score 2):

The [android developers web site](http://developer.android.com) has the new features for users and developers listed under the ["Android 3.2 platform"](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.2.html). Digging into that page, under the [revisions heading](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.2.html#relnotes) it lists "3.2, Revision 1" as the only revision. I would guess that this would be the 3.2.1 update then.

> **New user features**
>
> - Optimizations for a wider range of tablets
>
>   - Android 3.2 includes a
>       variety of optimizations across the system to ensure a great user
>       experience on a wider range of tablet devices.
> - Compatibility zoom for
>     fixed-sized apps
>
>   - Android 3.2 introduces a new compatibility zoom mode
>       that gives users a new way to view fixed-sized apps on larger devices.
>       The new mode provides a pixel-scaled alternative to the standard UI
>       stretching for apps that are not designed to run on larger screen
>       sizes, such as on tablets. The new mode is accessible to users from a
>       menu icon in the system bar, for apps that need compatibility support.
> - Media sync from SD card
>
>   - On devices that support an SD card, users can
>       now load media files directly from the SD card to apps that use them.
>       A system facility makes the files accessible to apps from the system
>       media store.

Comment: These were 3.2 feature additions, not 3.2.1. I am guessing 3.2.1 must be a bug/security release though it would be nice to know.